# Dúvida HTML Formulário de Cartão de Crédito

Tags: html, html5, semântica, pagamento-online, ui

Eu vi um formulário que sugere o cartão de credito que está no `autocomplete`. Mas sinceramente não entendi o que tem de diferente nesse forme que faz esse `autocomplete` funcionar?

Se os campos `input` do `form` não têm `type` como é identificado que é um form para colocar os dados do cartão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque o `form` abaixo funciona abrindo as infos do cartão de crédito? Como isso funciona?

Segue o código:

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="Card Number"/>
  <input placeholder="MM / YY" />
  <input placeholder="CVC"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Isso acontece com esse form em qualquer domínio? Eu não tenho cartão em autocomplete pra testar.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu não sei explicar, eu já fiz compras com cartão no meu pc, e esse forma simples ai já é o suficiente para tentar fazer o autocomplete, só não sei como definir isso... Olha ai como é https://imgur.com/HXXn04B e foi com o código desse form ai

Comment: Estou achando que ele (browser? plugin?) faz isso com base no texto do placeholder.

Comment: Eu mudei e mesmo assim abriu ... http://prntscr.com/pqt2f6 não sei dizer pq... No FireFox onde nunca comprei com cartão não abriu tb

Comment: E se o placeholder não der nenhuma dica, nem em pt? Sei lá, testa com "goiabada com queijo".

Comment: É bem possível que isso seja parte do sistema o qual está a utilizar.
Informações de cartão de credito são carregadas com base no usuário logado e um algoritimo JS detecta o capo com base em data- atributos ou aria roles, para exibir a popup.
Desconheço um recurso nativo para cartão de credito no HTML5

Comment: @Wesleyaraujo desconfio que seja um implantação do browser mesmo, e não do HTML, pq ainda não consigo entender como que ele faz o autocomplete com base no place holder, até pq aqui tem outro modelo que o placeholder é 0000 e mesmo assim ele acha o cartão! https://codepen.io/jeanoliveira/pen/XRZyVr teste ai

Comment: @bfavaretto da uma olhada nisso, artigo de 2016  https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/ eu estou até pensando em uma teoria da conspiração aqui haha, esse lance de "onde click buy", Google Pay, acho que a industria tem muito a ganhar facilitando a compra por impulso. Só não entendo como controlar esse tipo de form, só o placeholder ainda não me convenceu, dever ter uma explicação técnica

Comment: @hugocsl Realmente deve ser algo do browser, e possívelmente do chrome, (não testei em outros browser). Bom, achei esse artigo que da match com a sua (e agora nossa) curiosidade [checkout-faster-with-autofill](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill)

Comment: Pode ser que ele simplesmente sugira no primeiro campo, se não for de tipo conhecido. Meu gerenciador de senhas faz isso às vezes.

Comment: @Wesleyaraujo valeu a dica vou ler com calma

Answer (score -4):

Isso é cache do seu navegador, ele tenta aplicar o autocomplete nos campos de formulário de diversas formas, geralmente da prioridade para o id do campo (por isso é importante adicionar id em todos os campos, facilita o preenchimento com base em usos anteriores), mas o navegador tenta adivinhar do que se trata o campo pelo conteúdo do label, placeholder, etc...